# How can I clone a 20 GB Xbox 360 hard drive to a 32 GB USB drive?

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

My Xbox drive is beginning to fail which is why I need to get the data off of it. I have a game on the drive that is installed and the disc is scratched, so this is my only copy.

I need to clone the contents from the 20GB hard drive exactly onto a 32 GB USB drive. What is the simplest method of doing this? I have tried:

- Using Party Buffalo but using it doesn't even make sense. I can't actually view the files on the hard drive in question.
- Using HD Clone but apparently I need to pay for the product since the USB drive is a different size than the hard drive.

I have read many forums but the answers on these forums say things like:

> Either FTP the Content and Cache folders to your local PC (or copy to external USB HDD).
>
> Insert the new HDD and format in NXE.
>
> Install FSD
>
> Copy the folders back.

All of the replies on these forums use lingo I'm not entirely familiar with. I know my way around computers pretty well but what does it actually mean to FTP a folder, format in NXE, install FSD, copy folders back? I don't see how anyone could understand what that means.

I was always under the impression that cloning a HDD was a simple thing to do. Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Use Clonezilla instead. However you will need to burn into a disk or install it in another usb, different from the one you want to clone your disk into, this is a bit more technical then Clone HD but the results are equal if not better.

To follow your described approach you will need Filezilla is a free FTP tool, and pull your files from the Xbox:

Download and install Filezilla from https://filezilla-project.org/ Install and open Filezilla. Enter XBox IP into the Host field. (your local Xbox IP) Enter username and password (default username is "xbox" and default password is "xbox"). Click Quickconnect

Take your 32 Gb USB plug it into any USB port on the console and go to "Memory" in "System Settings" and select the Flash Drive and configure... This should take care of the format in NXE and install FSD part. At least for backup.

Then go to Filezilla and copy the files to the USB, you can also do this by making your USB the location you are in on the left of Filezilla or the "Local Site" side, and selecting all your files from the right and drag then to your right side or the USB.

You can also use Xbox and move stuff over to the Flash Drive. There is another way to transfer files is by buying a transfer cable from Microsoft and transfer files over to your PC.

Answer (score 0):

I had a program that worked for me when my flash drive had an error which switched it to read only and wouldnt work with the console any more.it let me read all the contents on thw memory card without any problems. it may work for you. I believe the program was called horizon. you should be able to connect the drive via usb to your computer I presume either using the 360 official adapter or by removing the drive and connecting via sata to usb adapter or maybe even strait from sata line.

as to the ftp im pretty sure they are assuming you have a modded console as ftp is a web file transfer protocol. I believe the other two acronims are for formats the console specifies for internal and external drives much as windows may use ntfs for the os drive and fat for the external and linux may use jfs or sda or a number of other file formatting.but the method I suggest above should let you see everything on your card as if it were in a 360 and be able to move it about as needed.best of luck...(fsd is frestyle dashboard nxe is the original style dashboard which are often custom unsigned apps possibly able to get you console banned)...not sure where your getting your advise but it seems pretty poor to me.you should be able to solve your problem as stated above just be sure to format your memory card for the 360 or even pull the drive from the new console and copy it straight over using horizon on the pc...